# Convex hull: known number of points but not points itself

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, convex-hull, convex

I need to find an algorithm which computes a convex hull from a given set of points `S` of size `n`.
I know that there are **exactly 6 points** from `S` which form the convex hull.

What is the best and **most efficient way** to compute this?

I thought about generating all possible combinations of points from `S` (which would be n choose 6 points) which would take O(n^6) and then check if this is a convex hull, which would take O(n) but lead into a very bad total runtime. There must be a better way. Any hints?

Comment: as a side note, nC6 is O(n^6), not O(n)

Comment: Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms

Comment: How about first checking here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms ? Edit: ninja'd

Comment: the convex hull is unique so why are you talking about 6 points etc just look up the algoritthm and execute it - its a minor problem if you have 1000 points or 10000 points it cannot be more than O(n^2)

Comment: Checking a 6-set takes O(N), so the total complexity would be O(N^7). Generally speaking, O(N^7) is just unthinkable, except for tiny N. For N=10, N^7 is already ten millions. For N=100, it is a hundred thousand billions.

Comment: How do you known that H=6 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If only 6 points lie on the convex hull then [Jarvis March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gift_wrapping_algorithm) or the Gift-wrapping algorithm would be very efficient. It runs in `O(nh)` time where `h` is the number of points on the convex hull.

Comment: It's worth adding to this that since h = 6 is a constant, this is an O(n) algorithm, which is provably optimal for the given problem: you must look at each point once, which means the problem's complexity is Ω(n).

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, the Jarvis March / Gift-wrapping algorithm is very quick in this instance, because the time complexity is `O(nh)`, compared with `O(nlogn)` in Graham Scan.

The only algorithm that comes to thought that would be quicker would be Chan's algorithm that runs in `O(nlogh)`, but since `h` is very small the difference would be marginal. Read more about Chan's algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chan%27s_algorithm).